# Cannot start Android Studio even after re installation

Tags: android-studio

I just disabled some plugins and then android studio stopped working. Asks me to re install it from scratch. I had installed it from snap store, so I uninstalled it from there and re installed it again from snap store. The problem persists. Please help me.

One thing that I noticed is that free disk space did not change at all when I uninstalled it from snap store. Which means it wasn't really deleted. [Click here to see the dialog that appears when I launch Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldcK1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Android Studio using umake:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android
```